# Chrome ignoring local dns replies

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, google-chrome, chrome, network-security

Am having a local network with about 300 devices some is domain connected and some are not
I have windows server 2012r2 sith dns role
Domain connected users can access local iis webpage while others cannot.
After searching and inspecting the problem was that chrome is not accepting my local dns as a secure dns so if i turn of secure dns on chrome everything works fine.
So any solution to be made without touching clients devices
Server sided solution
Where whenever anyone connects to my network buy not join the domain can take dns records as safe .
I tried nslookup and everything is fine the computer that isn,t connected to the domain is receiving the dns reply but chrome is ignoring and going to 8.8.8.8
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It looks like there is a GPO for managing this. Though, you’d need to touch endpoints for the configuration. https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#BuiltInDnsClientEnabled

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists (just like in my case), you have to disable some flags:
Navigate to edge://flags/ or chrome://flags/.
Disable #use-dns-https-svcb-alpn.
Disable #enable-async-dns (Chrome only).
Disable #encrypted-client-hello (Chrome only).

Source: https://www.bugdrivendevelopment.net/browser-ignore-internal-dns/